# Azure B2C Tenant failed with error "Tenant creation failed."

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently having issues trying to create my Azure AD B2C Tenant.

The error I am receiving is so useless and I am not sure where to start diagnosing it.

The Error: "Tenant creation failed."
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOrT5.png).

I have looked at my activity log aswell and this isn't very insightful as it stipulates it was accepted and nothing else: [Activity log Line Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMezv.png)

Where should I begin looking to get a better understanding of the issue if I need to produce a better error log?

I have tried this multiple times and get the same result.

Comment: Hi @Dylan could you please provide the repro steps/process you are doing, which will help us to investigate

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

Comment: @Dylan   Do you meet these two conditions: 1. You have the role of tenant administrator. 2. Your account has been assigned a subscription. I just created a b2c tenant for testing and it is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue when creating B2C tenant in 'South African' region. I tried 'United Kingdom' and it provisioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C team has started imposing limits on how many tenants can be created in subscription. Currently the limit is 20 B2C tenants per subscription. Can you try using a different subscription or deleting some tenants from the subscription to bring the number down below 20 to see if that works for you?

Azure AD B2C team is working on showing a more detailed error on the UI for such cases.